# Find and move files based on a date in the filename using bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I’m having problems with my batch file. I would like to find a file matching today’s date in the filename, i.e. my_file_20150320.pdf and then move it to a different directory, i.e. /tmp. Thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate more your question

Comment: i have filenames format nameofperson_YYYYmmDD.pdf, i.e. something_20150321.pdf, something_20150322.pdf, something_20150323.pdf, something_20150324.pdf and then move it to different directory if the file match today's date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3,4 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE /T') DO (
    SET yyyy=%%C
    SET mm=%%A
    SET dd=%%B
)
SET Today=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
MOVE "*%Today%.pdf" %1
```

Assuming that the batch file is called "moveTo.bat" and is in the same folder as the source files, it can be called like this:

```
moveTo "Destination folder name"
```

The parsing of the date depends on the date format of your system. The code above works on a US system, where the command:

```
DATE /T
```

returns: Sat 03/21/2015

Comment: thank you for your help it works but I want the batch file program has already set the source and destination of the folder, because i want to put the bat file program in the task scheduler. So that the bat file program it will check folder everyday.

Comment: So you can replace %1 by the destination folder, I guess.

Comment: Is there other way to revise the program instead of searching inside the folder and move to another folder? I want to search a directory like drive D, inside of it there's a folder. The bat file will be searched inside of the drive and will create a new folder. If the bat file found a new folder and move the files inside of the folder if the condition will match the date today.

Comment: I'd try to run the bat file but it didn't work. Since my file directory Source is in the Dropbox and the destination folder is in my local D. If I try to run the bat file nothing happen. Help me, What should I do? @ConnorsFan